# Should I perform data centering before apply SVD?

Tags: matlab, normalization, pca, svd

I have to use SVD in Matlab to obtain a reduced version of my data.
I've read that the function `svds(X,k)` performs the SVD and returns the first k eigenvalues and eigenvectors. There is not mention in the documentation if the data have to be normalized.
With normalization I mean both substraction of the mean value and division by the standard deviation.

When I implemented PCA, I used to normalize in such way. But I know that it is not needed when using the matlab function `pca()` because it computes the covariance matrix by using `cov()` which implicitly performs the normalization.

So, the question is. I need the projection matrix useful to reduce my n-dim data to k-dim ones by SVD. Should I perform data normalization of the train data (and therefore, the same normalization to further projected new data) or not?
Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Essentially, the answer is yes, you should typically perform normalization. The reason is that features can have very different scalings, and we typically do not want to take scaling into account when considering the uniqueness of features.

Suppose we have two features x and y, both with variance 1, but where x has a mean of 1 and y has a mean of 1000. Then the matrix of samples will look like

```
n = 500; % samples
x =   1  + randn(n,1);
y = 1000 + randn(n,1);
svd([x,y])
```

But the problem with this is that the scale of y (without normalizing) essentially washes out the small variations in x. Specifically, if we just examine the singular values of [x,y], we might be inclined to say that x is a linear factor of y (since one of the singular values is much smaller than the other). But actually, we know that that is not the case since x was generated independently.

In fact, you will often find that you only see the "real" data in a signal once we remove the mean. At the extremely end, you could image that we have some feature

```
z = 1e6 + sin(t)
```

Now if somebody just gave you those numbers, you might look at the sequence

```
z = 1000001.54, 1000001.2, 1000001.4,...
```

and just think, "that signal is boring, it basically is just 1e6 plus some round off terms...". But once we remove the mean, we see the signal for what it actually is... a very interesting and specific one indeed. So long story short, you should always remove the means and scale.

Comment: "So long story short, you should always remove the means and scale". This is simply incorrect, see my answer. There are many applications in which if a feature is twice as large it's also twice as reliable and in that case normalization makes no sense. The same goes for the mean, in many cases you want the mean to be part of the reduced dimension of the points, it all really depends on your problem

Answer (score 1):

It really depends on what you want to do with your data. Centering and scaling can be helpful to obtain principial components that are representative of the shape of the variations in the data, irrespective of the scaling. I would say it is mostly needed if you want to further use the principal components itself, particularly, if you want to visualize them. It can also help during classification since your scores will then be normalized which may help your classifier. However, it depends on the application since in some applications the energy also carries useful information that one should not discard - there is no general answer!

Now you write that all you need is "the projection matrix useful to reduce my n-dim data to k-dim ones by SVD". In this case, no need to center or scale anything:

```
[U,~] = svd(TrainingData);
RecudedData = U(:,k)'*TestData;
```

will do the job. The `svds` may be worth considering when your TrainingData is huge (in both dimensions) so that `svd` is too slow (if it is huge in one dimension, just apply svd to the gram matrix).

Comment: Basically I have sparse vectors. I want to "learn" some projection matrix from a training set to be used to downscale both train and test data. These projected vectors have to be fed to an SVM classifier (for train and test of course). 
So according to what you said, I don't need to substract from the train and test sets the mean of the train vectors. do I?

Comment: Well, if you feed them into a classifier then I would typically recommend to center and scale (unless scale itself is a relevant feature but this depends on your data which we know nothing about). This removes the influence of the scaling from the feature which could help to stabilize your SVM. See response from bremen_matt, who explains this aspect well.

Comment: By using svds(), the dimension of U result me as the number of training data by k! there is something wrong because it will not transform the test data from 1-by-n vectors to 1-by-k ones

Comment: Then, you are missing a transpose. The way I wrote it, I was expecting the training data to be the columns. If it is the rows, you need to transpose it.

Answer (score 0):

It depends!!!

A common use in signal processing where it makes no sense to normalize is noise reduction via dimensionality reduction in correlated signals where all the fearures are contiminated with a random gaussian noise with the same variance. In that case if the magnitude of a certain feature is twice as large it's snr is also approximately twice as large so normalizing the features makes no sense since it would just make the parts with the worse snr larger and the parts with the good snr smaller. You also don't need to subtract the mean in that case (like in PCA), the mean (or dc) isn't different then any other frequency.